# Fetching all the records for a partitionID in cassandra gives RPC timeout

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.2.1, composite key and trying to fetch all the records for a particular partitionID. Following is the schema I'm using:

- TimeStamp
- Device ID
- Data Transfer
- Location ID
- Device Owner

The primary Key is a composite key: (TimeStamp, Device ID). Therefore TimeStamp is the Partition key. Each record will be 70-80 bytes.

There are 1000 different TimeStamp, and for each timestamp, there are 500K Device IDs. So there are 500 million records, and I want to fetch all the records for a particular timestamp. Something similar to:

Select * from schema where TimeStamp = '..'

My understanding is that this query should be able to fetch all the records fast, since the relevant rows are all stored in contiguous disk location, which means very few disk seeks will give us the result. The filter is on TimeStamp, which means just one node will be hit with the query. Also, the total amount of data is 500K * 80 bytes ~ 40 MB, which is not an awful lot. However, I'm getting RPC Timeouts when I run this with CQL (3) or Astyanax.

Is my understanding that all the records for a partitionID are in contiguous disk location wrong? What should be the correct way to bulk fetch such a data?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the columns will be close to each other on disk because they are in the same row.  But before compaction is complete (i.e. assuming you don't run nodetool compact), they won't be.  But they should be split across a few SSTables.

However, the slower thing is probably CPU to deserialize, compare the results from the other replicas and serialize back to the client.  I doubt you can do that for 500k objects within rpc_timeout (default is 10 seconds).

To do this, you should page through the result.

For your first query, do

```
SELECT * from schema where TimeStamp = '..' limit 1000
```

Then take the last device ID and call it last:

```
SELECT 'last'..'' from schema where TimeStamp = '..' limit 1000
```

until you get fewer than 1000 columns in the response.

Comment: Richard, I have no replication, so comparison of results from other replicas should not be slowing things down.. right? Could you please elaborate what you mean by deserialize? Are you referring to latency introduced by processing the output from DB and sending the records on the network (over to client)?

I've run the compact command, will update if that helps. Are you aware of any other way I could benefit from the fact that data for a particular partitionID would be sequentially stored in DB, so that I could fetch it with minimum disk seeks? Thanks.

Comment: If you have no replication that will make it faster. By deserialize I mean Cassandra has to read the data off disk and construct Java objects from it. That is probably your bottleneck in this case - you can confirm by monitoring your server when running your query. Is it CPU bound (use top)? How much I/O does it do (use iostat)?

Comment: what you're saying probably means that no matter what I do (compact, etc.), I'll hit the bottleneck due to Java deserialization? Correct me if I am wrong. Are there any ways I can improve upon that?

Another input that I have is using the query 

Select count(*) from schema where TimeStamp = '..'

Also results in RPC Timeout. Now that should not happen if deserialization is the culprit, right? Do you have any ideas why count(*) would be so slow, and if compaction would help? Another input is there have only been inserts in my database, never entries were deleted.

Comment: Probably, yes. You should confirm by doing some monitoring though. Cassandra's query protocol is designed for small queries - returning 500k results is *a lot* for Cassandra. 'SELECT count' takes almost the same time as 'SELECT *' - inside Cassandra it does the 'SELECT *' query and just counts the results. The standard way to solve these problem is to use paging as in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I'll give it a shot, and update the results. Any pointers to how to do pagination using Astyanax would be helpful.

Comment: I did pagination with Astyanax, and that seems to have helped speed-up the response considerably. For fetching 500K records (total 40 GB), with pagesize of 1000 it takes 25 seconds approx. However, I'd like to know if serialization/deserialization overhead could be completely done away with, since that would further speed up things for me. The direction I'm thinking is that deserialization/serialization could be done on the client, and Cassandra should not spend any useful CPU cycles doing that. Let me know if I'm thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Great you got pagination working. You can't remove the deserialization/serialization work from Cassandra - it needs to read its own files off disk and make valid messages for the client. So there's very little you can do to speed this query up. If you had it in separate rows, you could parallelise the deserialization/serialization by having multiple client threads requesting different parts at once.

Comment: will having multiple threads help? I doubt it, but if the overhead of serialization/deserialization is too much, then may be concurrent serialization would help, even though there's just one disk resource. What do you think?

Comment: The problem with one row and one thread is that all the work inside Cassandra is done in one thread so can only use one CPU. If you had multiple rows and multiple client threads you could do the whole thing in parallel using all the CPUs on the server.

Comment: But how is it possible for pagination to be done on different CPUs? Wouldn't each thread have to co-ordinate with each other in order to know which pages to bring? Is that possible using any Cassandra Client (pycassa/Astyanax/etc.)? I understand that using more CPUs one can benefit provided the task can be 'subdivided' and run parallely. However, how can I write multithreaded code such that different threads bring different pages, without waiting for another thread to return its pages?

Comment: You can't do pagination in parallel. You can only do it if you can split your query into multiple rows. (This discussion is getting off topic - I think pagination is the answer you need. Happy to answer more questions on a new question.)

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments. I agree pagination is way forward.