# why the rpc timeout occur in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I tried using cqlsh -3 version on my keyspace and used select query on a column family.
It's return data in some causes and throws RPC time out in some other causes,I don't know the exact root cause.
I used select query with single where condition

```
select * FROM date where date='2013-10-11 00:00:00+0000';
```

In this date column has secondary index with datatype text in UTF8 format

```
Request did not complete within rpc_timeout.
```

I checked with cassandra log.it throws

```
ERROR [ReadStage:117] 2013-12-03 19:21:46,813 CassandraDaemon.java (line 192) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:117,5,main]
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableNamesIterator.read(SSTableNamesIterator.java:119)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableNamesIterator.<init>(SSTableNamesIterator.java:60)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.NamesQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(NamesQueryFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:68)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectTimeOrderedData(CollationController.java:132)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1390)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1213)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1125)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.keys.KeysSearcher$1.computeNext(KeysSearcher.java:191)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.keys.KeysSearcher$1.computeNext(KeysSearcher.java:109)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.filter(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1499)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.keys.KeysSearcher.search(KeysSearcher.java:82)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.index.SecondaryIndexManager.search(SecondaryIndexManager.java:548)
at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.search(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1487)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.RangeSliceVerbHandler.executeLocally(RangeSliceVerbHandler.java:44)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalRangeSliceRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1055)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1547)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

why this happening?
I am checking in my local with single seed?

Update 1:

my date table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE date (
  key text PRIMARY KEY,
  date text,
  date_id text,
  day bigint,
  day_name text
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  compaction={'min_sstable_size': '52428800', 'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'chunk_length_kb': '64', 'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};
```

I checked with cassandra log,Its shows

```
ERROR [ReadStage:94] 2013-12-03 22:07:17,116 CassandraDaemon.java (line 192) Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:94,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: DecoratedKey(-8665312888645846270,.......................<!--some bytes of numbers------->
/var/lib/cassandra/data/keyspace/columnfamily/keyspace-columnfamily-ic-1-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableNamesIterator.read(SSTableNamesIterator.java:119)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.columniterator.SSTableNamesIterator.<init>(SSTableNamesIterator.java:60)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.NamesQueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(NamesQueryFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.getSSTableColumnIterator(QueryFilter.java:68)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectTimeOrderedData(CollationController.java:132)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1390)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1213)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1125)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.getRow(Table.java:347)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceByNamesReadCommand.getRow(SliceByNamesReadCommand.java:64)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1033)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1547)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

currently i am using cassandra-1.2.6.
I check with this link,is this cassandra issue?
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4687

Comment: Could you add the query? (is it a very expensive one?)

Comment: Hi @lorcan ,I edited the question with query,please check and give your suggestions

Comment: Hi @kumar, yes, that **looks** like the same issue. Probably best to follow up there?

Comment: My answer still stands though - if you are indexing a lot of unique values in your `date` column and querying on that you should consider remodelling.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is expensive this can lead to rpc-timeouts. There's a bunch of SO questions along this line for different types of query, e.g., [Fetching all the records for a partitionID in cassandra gives RPC timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15492969/1051713), [RPC timeout in cqlsh - Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15238970/1051713) (select count(*) queries). However, your question relates specifically to secondary indices.

Querying on secondary indices should be avoided **if** the number of unique indexed entries is high, as they are much more expensive than querying by key (i suspect this is the case if you are using dates). Perhaps there is a better way of modelling your data? (If you add the data model to your question I can try to elaborate on this answer.)